# Is mindfulness meditation shirk

Tags: shirk

This is a Buddhist practice of meditation. I do not see it as a form of worship of other gods since all Buddhist forms of meditation have nothing to do with God or gods. I want to continue practicing this practice of meditation along with my salah prayers. Is this allowed? [Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mH2sEqrCza4) is the way I practice meditation.

However, I will abandon this practice if it is haram.

Comment: If it does not involve a budha or a statue or some sort it should be fine. However you do need to keep in mind that it is only Allah that is allowing you to achieve that peace of mind and no external sources. Shirk is when you associate something with Allah (swt). As long as you remember that and make sure to never associate antyhing with the Creator then it is fine. The way I see it is that this is like yoga and an exercise for the mind which is not haram. The best way to achieve peace would be listen to a recitation of the Qur'an and Salah also is very powerful.